# Books and shellcode examples

Tags: c, shellcode

i read "art of exploitation" and "gray hat hackers".Both these books examples written for x86 systems.i have a centrino laptop and an amd64 pc.I can't make work examples for stack based overflow.

Comment: Well, well, are you looking for support in hacking and breaking here? I'd vote down, but rep is < 100.

Comment: and... soo... ? what's your actual question? and most of us don't have those books... and I suspect in many cases we don't want to help you write exploit code. modding down for these reasons.

Comment: its' a valid question, he may well be doing security research.  All experts have to learn somehow.
(although I'm not naive enough to fully believe that)

Comment: these books' purpose is to learn the operating systems' security problems and so is mine

Answer (score 3):

On 64-bit  systems using ASLR, executable space protection makes it far more difficult to execute such attacks.  This may explain why you're failing to make them work.

I suggest reading [this paper](http://www.suse.de/~krahmer/no-nx.pdf) on x86-64 buffer overflow exploits for further information.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the example in Aleph One' article "Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit". You can find it here: [link text](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this day is not "aleph one" day more for our system this time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some virtualization software (like [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)) to run x86 system of your choice to play around also in amd64 system.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of protections built into OS and compilers to stop those exploits.  Or at least make them a heck of a lot more difficult: Noexec stacks, stack canaries, and so on.

Windows also uses stack monitoring as well.  Linux has similar features.  You really should consider taking your questions like these to a forum other than this one.